# Сохранение пользовательских настроек при выходе из приложения

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

У моей программы есть меню настроек которое позволяет менять разрешение окна и цвет шрифта. Нужно сделать так чтобы эти пользовательские настройки сохранялись и при повторном запуске их не приходилось менять.

Файл:

```
from tkinter import *
class App(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.root = Tk()
      self.master = self.root
      m = Menu(self.root)
      self.root.config(menu=m)
      cm = Menu(m)
      m.add_cascade(label="Color",menu=cm)
      cm.add_command(label="Default",command=self.colorD)
      cm.add_command(label="Red",command=self.colorR)
      cm.add_command(label="Green",command=self.colorG)
      cm.add_command(label="Blue",command=self.colorB)
      sm = Menu(m)
      m.add_cascade(label="Size",menu=sm)
      sm.add_command(label="500x500",command = 
              lambda:self.master.geometry('500x500'))
      sm.add_command(label="800x600",command = lambda: 
              self.master.geometry('800x600'))
      sm.add_command(label="1024x768",command = lambda: 
              self.master.geometry('1024x768'))
      self.txt = Text(self.root, font=('Arial',12))
      self.txt.pack()
  def colorD(self):
      self.txt.config(bg="white", fg="black")
  def colorR(self):  
      self.txt.config(bg="crimson", fg="yellow")
  def colorG(self):
      self.txt.config(bg="green", fg="blue")
  def colorB(self):
      self.txt.config(bg="skyblue", fg="dark violet")
  def on_execute(self):
      self.root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = App()
app.on_execute()
```

Способ сохранения данных может быть любым, главное чтобы было конкретное решение.

Comment: Огромная просьба не дублировать вопросы по несколько раз.

Comment: я этот вопрос задавал ночью, на него не ответили. утром чаще отвечают так то

Comment: То что на вопрос не ответили не означает, что нужно задавать еще один точно такой же.

Comment: мне пересказать этот вопрос или сидеть молча?

Comment: Как минимум можно отредактировать тот вопрос - тогда он поднимется в списке вопросов. Я бы посоветовал поправить отступы - сейчас там не код, а сплошная каша (впрочем, как и в этом вопросе). Дублировать вопросы точно не стоит.